# Treepanel masking

Tags: gwt, gxt

How can i mask tree panel until loader loads data from server??(At Initial loading)

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest thing to do is to call setVisible(false) on the TreePanel when you first create it and make it visible in your RPC callback.

A more visually elegant approach would be to use setEnabled(false) combined with a CSS style that changes the widget to a more neutral appearance to indicate that "there will be data here, but you can't use it yet".  You could do this by setting the background to a light grey color, or perhaps turning down the opacity of the panel.